# about Using Angular with ZK

Tags: angularjs

every one , I am learning about the demo which comes from https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2017/June/Using_Angular_with_ZK

and meet some issue like
https://images2018.cnblogs.com/blog/1107268/201808/1107268-20180807094750113-2116905420.png

seems the angular page always not show and the zk data also not show in the popup , if anyone knows about this , please kindly let me know